# Divisibility of $2^n-n^2$ by 7

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How many positive integers $n<10^4$ are there such that $2^n - n^2$ is divisible by 7?

Comment: Note that, $$2^{3}\equiv 1\pmod{7}$$ and, $$n\equiv 0,1,2,3,-3,-2,-1\pmod 7\implies n^2\equiv 0,1,4,2\pmod{7}$$ **Case 1.**  If $n=3x$ then your problem reduces to solving, $$2^{3x}\equiv (3x)^2\pmod 7\implies 9x^2\equiv1\pmod7$$

**Case 2.** If $n=3x+1$ then your problem reduces to solving, $$2^{3x+1}\equiv (3x+1)^2\pmod 7\implies 9x^2+6x \equiv 1\pmod7\implies 2x^2-x\equiv1\pmod 7$$

**Case 3.** If $n=3x+2$ then your problem reduces to solving, $$2^{3x+2}\equiv (3x+2)^2\pmod 7\implies 9x^2+12x \equiv 0\pmod7\implies 2x^2+5x\equiv 0\pmod{7}$$

Answer (score 4):

Just write out periods:

$2^n:2,4,1,2,4,1,2,4,1,2,4,1,2,4,1,2,4,1,2,4,1,|2...$ with period $3$

$n^2:1,4,2,2,4,1,0,1,4,2,2,4,1,0,1,4,2,2,4,1,0,|1...$ with period $7$

So in every $21$ numbers there are $6$ numbers.

Now just calculate $10^4\over 21$$=476$ and since $10000$ itself is not included there are $3$ remainder left so totally $6\cdot476+1=2857$ numbers.

Comment: A small mistake: $n$ should be strictly less that $10^4$, and so there are only $2857$ numbers.

Comment: You are right, will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

$10^4$ is small enough that it is possible to write a computer program to find the answer, but it is also possible to solve explicitly as follows:

We note that the possible remainders of $n^2$ modulo $7$ are $0, 1, 2$ and $4$. Since $2^n$ is never divisible by $7$, the possibilities that we have for which $2^n-n^2$ is divisible by $7$ are
$$ 2^n \equiv 1 \pmod 7 \quad\text{ and }\quad n \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 7$$
or
$$ 2^n \equiv 2 \pmod 7 \quad\text{ and }\quad n \equiv \pm 3 \pmod 7$$
or
$$ 2^n \equiv 4 \pmod 7 \quad\text{ and }\quad n \equiv \pm 2 \pmod 7$$

Now $2^n \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ if and only if $n \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, $2^n \equiv 2 \pmod 7$ if and only if $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, and $2^n \equiv 4 \pmod 7$ if and only if $n \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.

So our possibilities are
$$
\begin{align*}
  n & \equiv 0 \pmod 3 && \text{and} & n & \equiv 1 \pmod 7 \\
  n & \equiv 0 \pmod 3 && \text{and} & n & \equiv -1 \pmod 7 \\
  n & \equiv 1 \pmod 3 && \text{and} & n & \equiv 3 \pmod 7 \\
  n & \equiv 1 \pmod 3 && \text{and} & n & \equiv -3 \pmod 7 \\
  n & \equiv 2 \pmod 3 && \text{and} & n & \equiv 2 \pmod 7 \\
  n & \equiv 2 \pmod 3 && \text{and} & n & \equiv -2 \pmod 7
\end{align*}
$$

We can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find the solution to each pair of equations. We find that the possibilities for $n$ modulo $21$ are $15, 6, 10, 4, 2$ and $5$. Or, in order: $2, 4, 5, 6, 10, 15$ and $21$.

We now just need to count how many numbers there are with each remainder up to $10^4$. We have that $10^4 = 476 \times 21 + 4$, and so there are $476$ complete sets of $21$ numbers up to $10^4$, and $4$ extra. We find that the answer is $476 \times 6 + 1$ (Not $+2$ since we exclude $10^4$ since $n$ is strictly less than $10^4$) This is equal to $2857$.